# Problems with \pgfplotstableread and relative paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, pgfplotstable, paths, standalone

I have this folder structure in my project:

- main.tex
- mystyle.sty
- tex

  - mytex.tex
- img

  - myimg.tex
- dat

  - mydat.dat

And the following files:

main.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mystyle}

\begin{document}
  \input{tex/mytex}
\end{document}
```

mytex.tex:

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \input{img/myimg.tex}
\end{figure}
```

myimg.tex:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\IfStandalone{
  \newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{../dat/#1}
}{
  \newcommand{\fromRoot}[1]{./dat/#1}
}
\pgfplotstableread{\fromRoot{mydat.dat}}\datatable
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=10cm, height=6cm]
      \addplot table[x=0,y=1]{\datatable};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

mydat.dat:

```
1 0.4032
2 0.40241
3 0.38704
```

mystyle.sty:

```
\ProvidesPackage{mystyle}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
```

In my understanding should the path to the mydat.dat file be ./dat when I'm compiling the main file main.tex. But I always get the error message:

```
(./img/myimg.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
\pgfplotstableread@filename ^^@-\datatable
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, `standalone` removes all preambles (i.e. everything before `\begin{document}`) from the included `.tex` files, which is why `\datatable` isn't defined in the main document. You can either load `\usepackage[subpreambles]{standalone}` in your `main.tex` to include the preamble from `mytex.tex`, or you could move the macro after `\begin{document}`.