# Redefinition of pgfplotstableread and inline tables

Tags: pgfplotstable, tikz-external

I had to redefine `pgfplotstableread` because I use it in `standalone` files in an extra `img/` folder that loads data from a different `data/` folder as follows.

```
\begin{filecontents}{plot.tikz}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

\begin{document}
\tikzsetnextfilename{myplot}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table[row sep=\\] {
n err\\
1E3 1E-5\\
1E5 1E-9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzsetexternalprefix{img/}
\tikzexternalize
% define table read from image folder
\let\OLDpgfplotstableread\pgfplotstableread
\renewcommand{\pgfplotstableread}[1]{\OLDpgfplotstableread{img/#1}}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input{plot.tikz}
\end{document}
```

This apparently screws up my ability to use inline tables in `pgfplots` as this mwe does not compile. The whole external stuff is not necessary to reproduce the problem but is justification for the redefinition. A real MWE would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\let\OLDpgfplotstableread\pgfplotstableread
\renewcommand{\pgfplotstableread}[1]{\OLDpgfplotstableread{img/#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table{
n err
1E3 1E-5
1E5 1E-9
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way to have both features enabled at the same time (relative paths and inline tables)?

Comment: I don't think you need to redefine the command; have a look at [Problems with \pgfplotstableread and relative paths](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128468)

Comment: Does @cmhughes' comment help?

Comment: It shows a way to achieve what I want to do, yes. I'd prefer a solution where the standalone files are truly independent from the project but that might be impossible.

Comment: @cmhughes An answer maybe?

Comment: @percusse wouldn't it be a duplicate?

Comment: @cmhughes True.